Misidentified cell annotation from azimuth
I'm new to scRNAseq analysis, and am learning how to use Seurat v5 with lung datasets from public data sources (3 GSEs). my workflow is like this:

Load the datasets,
Filter by nFeature and percent mt
Run azimuth (on those separate datasets)
Merge datasets into one Seurat object
Normalize data, find variable features, scale, and run PCA
Integrate layers with harmony
Find neighbors and clusters

By this step, I found that of the cells annotated by azimuth as epithelial (in level 1), some of them at the finest level of detail are misidentified as immune and endothelial (cd8, cd4, macrophages, EC arterial and so on), even though the amount is very small.
Picture attached.
My questions are :

Was my workflow right?

Why are there some non epithelial cells (in the finest level) identified as epithelial cells (in level1) by azimuth annotation?

What should I do for the problem number two; am I safe to just ignore/remove it for further downstream analysis?


Thank you very much.
Epithelial cells (annotated by azimuth) with marker for epithelial, immune, and endothelial:

Cell count and visualization of proportion of each cells:

